# Visual studio no collapse / expand option

Tags: c#, python, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Im using visual studio community and i cant collapse / expand parts of my code anymore. The plus / minus symbol is just gone. So now i cant collapse functions, loops etc.

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE, i have outlining on. it just doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings and set

> "editor.folding": true
>
> "editor.foldingStrategy": "auto"
>
> "editor.showFoldingControls": "always"

Comment: Just noticed this is a visual studio code answer, as mentioned above i am using visual studio community not code.